# Multiple Background Images in IE, Using CSS to create multiple background images in IE

Tags: html, css

This is my first time posting here. I have a problem. I've been trying for ages to get multiple background images to work in both Chrome/Safari and IE. Of course it works in all browsers except IE.

**This my code:**

```
#container {
  width: 828px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  background-image: url('images/body.png'), url('images/filler.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
}
```

The reason I am using two background images is because I want the illustrated part to stay at the top, and have the white page background in the same div layer repeat when more content is added.

Right now this code works perfectly in Chrome, but NEITHER of the background images show up in Internet Explorer.

Help?

Comment: IE doesn't suport multiple background images. Not sure about !E9 but anything under that at least does not.

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If it´s possible I suggest you use two container elements.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  background: url('images/filler.png') repeat-y;
}
#inner-container {
  background: transparent url('images/body.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

Comment: @Manikandan Thangaraj: How does it occupy more space? It is the ultimate crossbrowser solution and how things have always been done. Otherwise you need to get a hardcore HTC or JS solution. Like css3pie.com. For the record, if you think double container is not a good solution and takes more space, then css3pie takes even more space and is even more harder to implement. Face it, you cant get a better fix then answered above.