# How can I show two background images, using internet explorer 6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I need to show two background images. I'm doing this:

```
table.grid thead.grid-header th
{
    background: url('../images/up-down-arrow.gif') no-repeat center right, url('../images/tt-caption-light.gif') repeat;
}
```

This work fine in internet explorer 11, but I need to do this for internet explorer 6. 
How can I resolve it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you still support IE6

Comment: You could try the suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106048/multiple-background-images-in-ie-using-css-to-create-multiple-background-images

Comment: Do you *really* need to do this for IE 6?

Comment: Because you really need to support the 0.66% of internet users on IE6... https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0

Comment: @Lyall: Could be for a bank or something that (for some weird reason) refuses to upgrade.  I had to support IE 7 for a while because of that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I understand supporting older versions for large corporations where upgrading is a hassle, I had to do it for 8 and 9. But I'm not aware of any organisations still using IE6 now. IE6 was shipped with XP, but XP can be used with later versions of IE (up to version 9 I think?). I think catering for old versions is one thing but catering for SUCH old versions is not necessary unless, like you say, it's all they can use.

Comment: Yes, is for a specific client that use only IE6.

Comment: Slap your client, and get them to install a modern web browser.

Comment: What client cares enough about how something looks that he wants, not one, but _two_ backgrounds, yet doesn't update their browser? This is the kind of occasion where you need to go to your client and say 'No, because the time it costs to do this is not worth the benefit of having two backgrounds in an old _unsupported_ browser.'